# Changing color on screen depending on ascending value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

lets say I have value in the background of my which is permanently changing. I want it to change the background color with a nice fading.

This is what I'm currently doing:
I have an Timer which reads the value every second and then chooses the new color and fades it via CAAnimation like this:

```
CABasicAnimation* fade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
fade.fromValue = (id)self.view.backgroundColor.CGColor;
[self.view setBackgroundColor:changeColor];
fade.toValue = (id)changeColor.CGColor;
[fade setDuration:0.5];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:fade forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
```

This works in fact ok because the animation is shorter than the actual timer so it looks alright but a bit sloppy.

How can I do this permanently and smooth without a timer?

Comment: Why have you not made the animation duration the same as the timer period?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Why don't you include the code for your NSTimer's selector too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using UIView animations. You could use a method like animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:, to animate a single color transition, and in the completion block trigger the next color change. In order to avoid nesting animation blocks many levels deep in completion methods, I sometimes have a method that uses an instance variable to keep track of a step counter, and the completion block just increments the step counter and calls the method again.

If you can limit your app to iOS 7, there is a new keyframe animation that you could use to animate through a whole series of colors.

There is a demo project from ShinobiControls that does exactly what you want. Check this link:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/04/ios7-day-by-day-day-11-uiview-key-frame-animations